# Make the information windows disappear when the mouse move out in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I need to Showing the location of a marker in its tip when moving cursor over it.
when I move on the marker, it shows the location. when I move away, the information windows does not disappear. that is confusing. Maybe something wrong with my code. The code is:

```
    function moveInfoWindow(marker, message) {

        var moveWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: message
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {
            moveWindow.open(map, marker);
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', function() {
            moveWindow.close();
        });
    }
```

With the following result:

[image]

Comment: Please add code to the questions. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Try chaning your code like this:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', (function(infowindow){ 
        return function() {
           infowindow.close();
        };
```